# How can I get a property of an entity without having to call getEntityByType every time?

Tags: javascript, impactjs

I'm trying to get an entity (a bullet, a grenade, and an explosive) from my player. Specifically, I want the `shootingRate` of my bullet (how frequently it can be fired).

How can I do this without having to call `getEntityByType` each time I fire this projectile? There has got to be a cleaner way from what I'm doing right now, which is:

```
// Shooting
var isShooting = ig.input.state('shoot');

if (isShooting && this.lastShootTimer.delta() > 0) {

switch (this.activeWeapon)
{
    case("EntityBullet"):
        ig.game.spawnEntity(this.activeWeapon, this.pos.x, this.pos.y - 10);
        var equipedWeap =  ig.game.getEntitiesByType(EntityBullet);
        this.lastShootTimer.set(equippedWeap.shootingRate);
        console.log(equipedWeap.shootingRate);
        break;
    case("EntityGrenade"):
        ig.game.spawnEntity(this.activeWeapon, this.pos.x, this.pos.y +5);
      var  equipedWeap =  ig.game.getEntitiesByType(EntityGrenade);
        this.lastShootTimer.set(equipedWeap.shootingRate);
        console.log(EquipedWeap.shootingRate);
        break;
    case("EntityExplosiveBomb"):
        ig.game.spawnEntity(this.activeWeapon, this.pos.x, this.pos.y +5 );
     var   equipedWeap =  ig.game.getEntitiesByType(EntityExplosiveBomb)[0];
        this.lastShootTimer.set(equipedWeap.shootingRate);
        console.log(equipedWeap.shootingRate);
        break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just have a look at the documentation on spawnEntity : it returns the newly created entity.

```
// Shooting
var isShooting = ig.input.state('shoot');

if (isShooting && this.lastShootTimer.delta() > 0) {
   var spawnWeap = ig.game.spawnEntity(this.activeWeapon, 
                                         this.pos.x, this.pos.y , 
                                             { gunnerflip : this.currentAnim.flip, 
                                                gunnerSize : this.size });
   this.lastShootTimer.set(spawnWeap.shootingRate);
 }
```

Rq 1 : You'll notice i didn't handle here the (x,y) shift linked to each weapon : i think you should handle it in the init() of each weapon, that's why i sent the flip and the size of the weapon user in the settings.

Rq 2 : you need to make a distinction between a weapon and its 'bullets'.

Rq 3 : Things might be simpler if you have, for each weapon, a canShoot function, that handles both the fire rate and the bullets remaining, and maybe some other conditions (overheat, ...). 
If you also implement a shoot() function that takes the shooting entity as an argument, your code becomes :

```
// Shooting
var isShooting = ig.input.state('shoot');

if (isShooting && this.activeWeapon.canShoot()) {
    this.activeWeapon.shoot(this);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a constant at the top level of your scope:

```
// constants
var PLAYER_SHOOTING_RATE = 2;
```